# Python Parser- Trying to process a 400 MB file for a special string.. I see the following code works when file size is small

Tags: python, file, parsing, automation

```
import re
string1 = "tabCause"
file_name=input("enter file name:")
  
# opening a text file
#file1 = open(file_name, "r",buffering=100000)
  
# setting flag and index to 0
flag = 0
index = 0
tablish_cause1 = 0
tablish_cause2 = 0 
other_tablish_cause = 0
  
  
# Loop through the file line by line
with open(file_name,'r') as file1:
    #for line in f:
     #   print line
    for line in file1:  
        index += 1
        print(line)
        # checking string is present in line or not
        if 'tabCause' in line:
            print("found",index,line)  
            flag = 1  
        #continue
        
print(index)        
file1.close() 
          
# checking condition for string found or not
if flag == 0: 
   print('String', string1 , 'Not Found') 
else: 
   print('String', string1,'found')

# closing text file
```

when file size is 1 MB , I see script is able to find the string. However for larger sizes of 5 MB or 10 MB it fails. I see that print is able to print and reab bigger files upto 400 MB but searching the string is failing

**

- Success output with 1 MB File

**

py String_Search.py
enter file name:test56.txt

found 3 (H:0xeb41), tabCause(2) !!

3

String tabCause found

**

- Failed output with 5 MB file or more

**

enter file name:test12.txt

36833

String tabCause Not Found

Comment: How does it "fail?" Is there an error? What is the actual output and what is the expected output for each case?

Comment: @MichaelRuth if fails , it prints "String tabCause Not Found" .. Expected output is 'String tabCause found' .. for 1 MB file I see 'found' string. However when I feed 400 MB file , which has string ( based on visual inspection using notepad++).. it dumps 'String tabCause Not Found'

Comment: @MichaelRuth , I have added the sample output to the description above

Comment: Cannot reproduce. I created a 500MB file with "tabCause" in it on multiple lines and the script found all occurrences of it. What is the output of `grep "tabCause" test12.txt`? Or `findstr "tabCause" test12.txt"` in Windows?

Comment: Interesting pointer @MichaelRuth, grep and finstr is not returning output for test12.txt , however I see valid output for test56.txt. I tried vi test12.txt and it looks garbage chars.. however I am able to read it in Notepad++ and notepad.. any reason why that would happen ?

Comment: Sounds like an encoding/decoding issue. You can specify an encoding with a kwarg to `open` like this: `open("test12.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8")`. I don't know how these files were encoded but my best guesses are utf-8 or cp1252. The `chardet` package can help guess encoding as well.